# Named parameters not bound

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, createquery

I have a multiple HQL statements which is vulnerable to the SQL injection example:

```java
public List<Person> SearchList(String userName, String firstName, String lastName, String email) Exception {
   List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
   String hql = " FROM **.***.***.entity.Person P WHERE ";
   boolean buName = false;
   boolean bfName = false;
   if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(userName)){
      hql = hql + "lower(P.userName) like :userName "; 
      buName = true;
   }
   if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(firstName) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(lastName)){    
      if(buName){
         hql = hql + " OR ";
      }
      hql = hql + "(lower(P.firstName) like :firstName AND lower(P.lastName) like :lastName) ";  
      bfName = true;    
   }
   if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(internetAddr)){    
      if(buName || bfName){
         hql = hql + " OR ";
      }
      hql = hql + "lower(P.email) = :email"; 
   }
   try {
      Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
        
      if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(userName)) {
         query.setParameter("userName", '%'+userName.toLowerCase()+'%');
      } else if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(firstName) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(lastName)) {
         query.setParameter("firstName", '%'+firstName.toLowerCase()+'%');
         query.setParameter("lastName", '%'+lastName.toLowerCase()+'%');
      } else if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(email)) {
         query.setParameter("email", email.toLowerCase());
      }

      personList = query.list();
   } catch(Exception e){
      throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
   }
   return personList;
}
```

Here I am avoiding concatenations in the query `"'%" + userName + "%'"` to avoid SQL injection vulnerability and now I am seeing exceptions related to

```
Named parameters not bound: lastname
```

This happens based the searches with `firstname`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Using and setting parameters in JDBC is safe from SQL injection attacks.  SQL injection attacks happen when someone can inject stuff into the actual SQL statement itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correct this:

```java
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(userName)) {
   query.setParameter("userName", '%'+userName.toLowerCase()+'%');
} else if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(firstName) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(lastName)) {
   query.setParameter("firstName", '%'+firstName.toLowerCase()+'%');
   query.setParameter("lastName", '%'+lastName.toLowerCase()+'%');
} else if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(email)) {
   query.setParameter("email", email.toLowerCase());
}
```

to this:

```java
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(userName)) {
   query.setParameter("userName", '%'+userName.toLowerCase()+'%');
}
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(firstName) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(lastName)) {
   query.setParameter("firstName", '%'+firstName.toLowerCase()+'%');
   query.setParameter("lastName", '%'+lastName.toLowerCase()+'%');
}
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(email)) {
   query.setParameter("email", email.toLowerCase());
}
```

as you should add named parameters to HQL and set them via `query.setParameter` consistently.

**NOTE**

> I am avoiding concatenations in the query "'%" + userName + "%'" to avoid SQL injection vulnerability

You can use [concatenation (operation)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-concatenation) in HQL like below:

```
... 
lower(P.userName) like '%' || :userName || '%'
...
```

It will allow you to avoid SQL injection too. But please note that this `like` most likely will lead to the [full table scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan).